# How to use float in an array in c

Tags: c, arrays

i want to use float values inside the array for example,

```
array[4];

array[0] = 3.544
array[1] = 5.544
array[2] = 6.544
array[3] = 6.544

float array[] (is giving me error)
```

but i dont know how to use help me, i am a c beginner

Comment: You are missign SOMETHING in your example. `float array[4];` should work just fine. Doing another declaration obviously won't.

Comment: Please post actual code. Also, please say what error you are getting. Finally, remove the C++ tag if your programming language is C.

Comment: hey @Kishan! Please select the best answer and accept the answer. This is how stackoverflow works.!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initialize an array in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to specify the size if you are going to define array float in this way:

```
float array[4];
```

You can define the array without the size. but it should be in this way:

```
float array[] = {3.544, 5.544, 6.544, 6.544};
```

see the following topic for more details: [How to initialize all members of an array to the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c)

Comment: little note: put on the F at the end, they are floats {3.544F, 5.544F, 6.544F, 6.544F};

Comment: @Exceptyon, why?, there is no need to such thing

Comment: @DavidRF: The result of `float x = 3.544;` is the decimal numeral “3.544” converted to `double` and then converted again to `float`. For certain rare numerals, this double conversion produces a different result than converting a numeral suffixed with “f” directly to `float`. In addition, there circumstances, other than initialization or direct assignment of a floating-point object, in which the use of `double` rather than `float` changes the semantics of C expressions.

Answer (score 2):

```
float array[4];

array[0] = 3.544;
array[1] = 5.544;
array[2] = 6.544;
array[3] = 6.544;
```

This should work buddy.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an array with no static size.

You can create an array like this on the stack, which is mostly when you have smaller arrays:

```
float myarray[12];
```

it is created in the scope and destroyed when that scope is left.

or you can create large arrays using `malloc` in C, the are allocated on the heap, these need to be 
manually destroyed, they live until you do so:

```
// create array dynamically in C
float* myheaparr = malloc(sizeof(float) * 12);

//do stuff with array


// free memory again.
free(myheaparr);
```

Comment: This answer is confusing. It presents two allocations in one set of source code. That is either pointless or is a failure to separate the examples and to state the purpose of each one.

Answer (score 0):

Specify number of elements you wanna work with while declaring.

float array[number of elements];

this will statically allocate memory for  specified. Access each elements with index. eg

float array[4] will statically allocate memory for 4 floating point variables. 
array[0] refers to the first element and so on.

Comment: This is a static allocation at file scope, an automatic allocation at block scope.